# ActiveRecord associations with two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around how I should be configuring my tables + associations.

I have a `Lawsuit` model. A lawsuit `has_many` parties (defendants, plaintiffs, attorneys, etc.). A party, in turn, can either be a `Person` or a `Company`. Ultimately, I want to be able to get:

- A person’s lawsuits (`@person.lawsuits`);
- A company’s lawsuits (`@company.lawsuits`); and
- A lawsuit’s parties (`@lawsuit.parties`), which can be either `people` or `companies`.

This is how I have my tables + models set up currently:

people

```
| id | fname  | lname | date_of_birth |
| -- | ------ | ----- | ------------- |
|  1 | John   | Smith |    1974-02-04 |
|  2 | George | Glass |    1963-07-29 |
```

companies

```
| id | name      | duns      | ticker | address      |
| -- | --------- | --------- | ------ | ------------ |
|  1 | Acme Inc. | 239423243 | ACME   | 123 Main St. |
```

lawsuits

```
| id | jurisdiction | court | case_no    | title                       |
| -- | ------------ | ----- | ---------- | --------------------------- |
|  1 |      federal | SDNY  | 18-CV-1234 | Smith v. Glass, Acme, et al |
```

lawsuit_parties

```
| id | lawsuit_id | person_id | company_id | role      |
| -- | ---------- | --------- | ---------- | --------- |
|  1 |          1 |         1 |            | plaintiff |
|  2 |          1 |         2 |            | defendant |
|  3 |          1 |           |          1 | defendant |
```

```rb
# models/lawsuit.rb:
class Lawsuit < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lawsuit_parties

    def parties
        self.lawsuit_parties
    end

    def defendants
        self.parties(where(lawsuit_parties: {role: 'defendant'})
    end

    def plaintiffs
        self.parties(where(lawsuit_parties: {role: 'plaintiff'})
    end

    def attorneys
        self.parties(where(lawsuit_parties: {role: 'attorney'})
    end
end
```

```rb
# models/lawsuit_party.rb
class LawsuitParty < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :company
end
```

```rb
# models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lawsuit_parties
    has_many :lawsuits, through: :lawsuit_parties
end
```

```rb
# models/company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lawsuit_parties
    has_many :lawsuits, through: :lawsuit_parties
end
```

Any help you would be much appreciated…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you'll need to introduce a [polymorphic relationship](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) onto your Join Model to get this type of modeling to work.  [An Enum can handle differentiating between Defendants and Plaintiffs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), as well as provide several scopes/methods you're asking for for free.

```
class LawsuitParty < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :lawsuit
    belongs_to :partiable, polymorphic: true

    enum role: [:defendant, :plaintiff]
end
```

You'll need to write a migration to change your `lawsuit_parties` table to the following columns (all Rails convention names):

```
partiable_id   = Integer
partiable_type = String
role           = String

lawsuit_parties

| id | lawsuit_id | partiable_id | partiable_type | role      | 
| -- | ---------- | ------------ | -------------- | ----------|
|  1 |          1 |            1 | Person         | defendant |
|  2 |          1 |            2 | Company        | plaintiff |
|  3 |          1 |            1 | Company        | defendant |
```

Next, tell Rails that `Person` and `Company` records are associated with many `Lawsuit`'s using `has_many`'s `:as` option.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lawsuit_parties, as: :partiable
    has_many :lawsuits, through: :lawsuit_parties
end
```

Add the same `has_many :lawsuit_parties, as: :partiable` to Company, or any other models that may come later (i.e. `Judge` or `JuryMember`).

Once you have a LawsuitParty setup like this, you should be all set.

Comment: I think this is getting me there, thank you!

To create an association, `@lawsuit.lawsuit_parties << Person.first` gets me the following error:

```ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (LawsuitParty(#70357266387440) expected, got #<Person id: 1, fname: "John", lname: "Doe", created_at: "2019-01-21 04:07:20", updated_at: "2019-01-21 04:07:20"> which is an instance of Person(#70357238653680))
```

Do I need to create the `LawsuitParty` record manually (`@lawsuit.lawsuit_parties.create(paritable_type: "Person", role "plaintiff"), or are there shortcut methods for this?

Comment: Glad to help.  You defined `parties` to map to LawsuitParty records somewhere.  That error is telling you that you're trying to shovel a record of the wrong type onto that association.  I don't know your DSL fully, but perhaps you meant to `@lawsuit.people << Person.first` ??

Comment: Ah, typo on my part. I had added a `parties` method to the Lawsuit model that returns `self.lawsuit_parties`). So my question is that once the relationships and tables are established, what is the standard way to add a person, company, etc. to a lawsuit’s parties. E.g., `@lawsuit.lawsuit_parties << Person.first` (but that's what returns the above error).

Comment: def parties; self.lawsuit_parties; end - is the problem.  Simple thing to do so you don't have to fiddle with Rails too much is to define an "add_party_as(partiable:, role:)" method on Lawsuit.  Define how to add a party there.  It would be something like `self.lawsuit_parties.create(args)`.